# How to run a shell script from the jar file created if shell script is present in the jar itself?

Tags: java, shell, maven, sh

I want to run the shell script from the jar created of the maven JAVA project. I want to trigger that shell script through ProcessBuilder, but I am not getting, how can I take the path of shell script. My shell Script is in the src/main/resources folder in my project. Shell Script also takes one argument to execute(both shell script and the args file to shell script are in same path mentioned above). Please can anybody help me is how can I run the shell script from my jar file.

Comment: its not a solution but can be possible by copying the script to local directory from jar and then execute it.

Comment: Get the `InputStream` of your script with the `ClassLoader.getResource()`, dump its content into the `OutputStream` returned from `ProcessBuilder.getOutputStream()` and run `bash -s`. The idea sounds good, but I didn't have time to test it yet.